# multiple of specific Number condition operator

Tags: magento2

in magneto 2 we have condition operators such as

```
$operators = [
            '>=' => __('equals or greater than'),
            '<=' => __('equals or less than'),
            '>' => __('greater than'),
            '<' => __('less than'),
        ];
```

is there any operator for "multiple of specific number"

e.g:

multiple of 2 is 4,6,8,10

multiple of 3 is 6,9,12,15

kindly advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use PHP's fmod function?

I.e. "Is X a multiple of Y?"

- Is 20 a multiple of 4?
  `$multiple = fmod(20, 4)==0; if($multiple){...}`
  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php